# combine_pdf not combining the pdfs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think I am missing something simple.  Using [combine_pdf](https://rubygems.org/gems/combine_pdf): I am attempting to combine two pdf files into one pdf, and then send that resulting pdf with `send_data` in my rails app.

Here is my code in a controller:

```
pdf = CombinePDF.new

# returns an array, each element is a string of an absolute path 
# to the file I want to upload
absolute_upload_paths = @obj.attachments.collect {|obj| obj.my_attachment.path}

absolute_upload_paths.each {|upload_path| pdf << CombinePDF.load(upload_path)}

send_data pdf, filename: “my_combined_pdf”, type: "application/pdf"
```

What results is that a damaged pdf file gets sent which cannot be opened:

> Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open 'VR_Voc_Eval-51.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

What am I missing? How can I use this gem to combine two existing pdf files into one pdf and then send it to the user?

Comment: When a larger integration isn't working it's best to break down the problem into smaller pieces. Can you merge the pdfs from a rails or ruby console using hardcoded file paths? Once that's working you can move onto verifying merging files from your models and returning the file from rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the README for that library calls .to_pdf when sending the data. Hopefully calling #to_pdf on the pdf object like in the example will fix your issue.

```
send_data pdf.to_pdf, filename: “my_combined_pdf”, type: "application/pdf"
```

https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf#rendering-pdf-data

Comment: That was it, needed the `.to_pdf`.  Thank you!